# What is the datetime format to retrieve Google Analytics data?

Tags: java, google-analytics

I am getting data from Google Analytics with this simple query:

```
Get apiQuery = analytics.data().ga().get("ga:0000000", ID="ga"+ProfileID
                startDate, // Start date
                endDate, // End date
                "ga:totalEvents"); // Metrics
```

Right now, my start date is in format: `yyyy-MM-dd`. However, I would like to include time as well, so I get delta data every hour.

Is it even possible? If it is, what is the correct date format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you specified can take only start time and end time in yyyy-MM-dd format.

But there is another function to retrieve real time data.It may be help ful to you.

analytics.data().realtime()
    .get("ga:ProfileId",
         "rt:activeUsers")
    .setDimensions("rt:medium");

You can see information at:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/reference/data/realtime/get